# How do I change a CSS property with a . in its name?

Tags: javascript, css

In a website I am trying to make a theme for, they have a CSS name **ul.menu li ul** and I want to change the **border-top** property of it. I know how to do it with simple CSS names like **mycssname** but how do I do this with a dot in JavaScript?

I have tried these:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ul.menu li ul")[0].style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff"
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ul.menu li ul")[0].style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff"
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ul")["menu li ul"].style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff"
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="ddm" style="display: block;">
```

When I inspect it, it shows the modifiable value of **ul.menu li u** in the CSS inspector.

But all of them give an Error of a Undefined.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the HTML so we have a better understanding of the thing you want to add a style to?

Comment: @FoundingBox done. I added the HTML.

Comment: Clearly, with the given HTML there will be no DOM element that fits your CSS selectors  `"ul.menu li ul"` and `"ul.menu li ul"`. And what do you expect `document.getElementsByClassName("ul")["menu li ul"]` to return?.

Comment: `ul.menu` is looking for an element like `<ul class="menu">`, the example you provided is `<ul class="ddm">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, the following does in fact work.

```js
document.querySelector('ul.menu li ul').style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff";
```

However, the site in reference (https://v3rmillion.net) has *two* elements matching that selector. They are only visible on hover. (Home & Misc)

Therefore, we need to alter the code to update *all* elements matching the selector:

```js
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu li ul')].forEach(el => {
     el.style.borderTop = '5px solid #fff';
})
```

Alternatively, if you just want to update the second element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu li ul')[1].style.borderTop = '5px solid #fff';
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use CSS selector with `getElementsByClassName()`,  you must define a class name for it.
so, you can do:

`document.querySelector("ul.menu li ul").style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff"`

Or,

`document.querySelectorAll("ul.menu li ul")[0].style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff"`

Comment: These do not work. I'm not sure I think it might be because It's not **ul.menu li ul** but I really think it is.

Comment: OP updated the question, the unordered list (ul) element has a different class name, `ul.ddm li ul` might work with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the selector as a parameter of `querySelector()` method:

```
document.querySelector('ul.menu li ul').style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff";
```

I see that more than one element in your site matches that selector, so you will have to set the styles to all such elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu li ul').forEach(e=>e.style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff");
```

Comment: It outputted **"5px solid #fff"** but it's not working. Please check at https://v3rmillion.net/index.php if possible. When you hover over 'misc' button and you see the little red bar I'm trying to change that.

Comment: Pleas test with the updated snippet with `querySelectorAll`

Comment: You have two elements, that match the selector one of them is the dropdown for `Home` and the other one is for `Misc`. Using the first snippet you apply the styles only to the `Home` dropdown.

Comment: What would I have to use for Misc?

Comment: The second snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding class property to element instead of using hierarchy.

```
<h1 class="app"> Hello world </h1>
document.getElementsByClassName("app").style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff"
```

Comment: How do I do this if I don't own the website?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ddm");
    elements[0].style.borderTop = "5px solid #fff";
```

Answer (score 0):

Read docs for [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) :

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an
> array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
> class name(s).

Keep in mind CSS selectors read right-to-left, your selector is expecting something like this structure:

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <ul></ul> <!-- style this element -->
  </li>
</ul
```

There is no element with those *class*es. More precisely `li` and `ul` are not even classes but HTML tag names.

Using either [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will be more appropriate based on whether you want only first matching element or all the matching elements. Both of these methods accept css selector.